# remove css style with regex in c#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, regex, styles

i want edit width properties from html tags and inline style from string in c# 
for example convert width="54px" (or style="width:54px") to width="54px" or (style="width:100%")
in my string maybe some  width like this: **width='54px'** (not with double quotation )
like this:

```
<div width= " 25px " ></div>
<div Width= " 63453px   "   ></div>
<div width='15px' ></div>
<div width= ' 15px' ></div>
<div Width= ' 15px' ></div>
<div width="1 "  ></div>
<div Width=  " 45"></div>
<div width="  5454px  "></div>
<div width="54px"></div>
<div width="54px" style="width:54px"> </div>
```

i try this method for do this:

```
  public string _ConvertTagWidth2(string content)
{
    string patern1 = "width=\".\\w*\"";
    string patern2 = "width='.\\w*'";

    string replace1 = "width=\"100%\"";
    string replace2 = "width:'100%'";

    string output = Regex.Replace(content, patern1, replace1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    output = Regex.Replace(output, patern2, replace2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    return output;
}
```

but the outpou  this:

```
<div width= " 25px " ></div>
<div Width= " 63453px   "   ></div>

<div width:'100%' ></div>
<div width= ' 15px' ></div>
<div Width= ' 15px' ></div>

<div width="1 "  ></div>
<div Width=  " 45"></div>

<div width="  5454px  "></div>
<div width="100%"></div>
<div width="100%" style="width:54px"> </div>
```

how can i fix regex to do this solution

Answer (score 0):

i solved by help of [regular tester](http://www.regexr.com/)

(width=)(\s+"|")(\d+px"|\s+\d+px"|\s+\d+px\s+"|\d+px\s+")